# Angular JS ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am developing an app like tinder, I am succeeded in creating the swipe-left and swipe-right effect, I am using ng-repeat there, but i want that the card should not repeat until all the cards swaped once.

Here is my code :-

---

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Tinder Clone</title>
    <link href="http://112.196.33.85/solitaire/demoui/john/10oct/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://112.196.33.85/solitaire/demoui/john/10oct/js/custom.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://112.196.33.85/solitaire/demoui/john/10oct/js/cards.js"></script>

<style>
.ionic-logo {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
}
.pane {
  background-color: #333 !important
}
.bar.bar-transparent {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: none;
}
.bar .title {
  color: #eee;
}
.swipe-cards {
  position: fixed;
}
.swipe-card {
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
  -moz-perspective: 1000;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 245px;
  margin-left: -150px;
  margin-top: -150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.swipe-card .title {
  height: 0px;
  /*padding: 5px;*/
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #444;
}
.swipe-card .image {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 250px;
}
.swipe-card .button {
  border: none;
}
.swipe-card .image img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px; min-height:200px; max-height:200px;
}
#start-card {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #30BD8A;
  line-height: 300px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border: 6px solid #4CD68E;
  text-align: center;
}
#start-card span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#footer .button {
  color: #fff;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0,0);
  }
  70% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bounceIn {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scale(0,0);
  }
  70% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scale(1,1);
  }
}

.swipe-card.pop-in-start {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0,0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0,0);
}
.swipe-card.pop-in {
  -webkit-animation: bounceIn 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-animation: bounceIn 0.3s ease-out;
}
</style>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter" animation="slide-left-right-ios7" no-scroll>
    <pane ng-controller="CardsCtrl" class="pane">
      <header-bar type="bar-transparent" title="'Help out'"></header-bar>
      <p style="color:white; display:none;">Accepted: {{accepted}}, Rejected: {{rejected}}</p>
      <swipe-cards>
        <swipe-card on-swipe="cardSwiped()" id="start-card">
          <img src="images/pic1.jpg" alt=""/>
        </swipe-card>
        <swipe-card ng-repeat="card in cards" on-swipe="cardSwiped($index)">
          <div ng-controller="CardCtrl">
            <div class="title">
              {{card.title}}
            </div>
            <div class="image">
              <img ng-src="{{card.image}}">
            </div>
            <div class="button-bar">
              <button style="color:red;" class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="reject()">UGH</button>
              <button style="color:green;" class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="accept()">YUM</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </swipe-card>
      </swipe-cards>
    </pane>
    <script>
    angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ionic.contrib.ui.cards'])

.directive('noScroll', function($document) {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr) {

      $document.on('touchmove', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    }
  }
})

.controller('CardsCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSwipeCardDelegate,  $rootScope) {   
  $rootScope.accepted = 0;
  $rootScope.rejected = 0;
  var cardTypes = [
    { title: '', image: 'images/pic1.jpg' },
    { title: '', image: 'images/pic2.jpg' },
    { title: '', image: 'images/pic3.jpg' },
    { title: '', image: 'images/pic4.jpg' },
    { title: '', image: 'images/pic5.jpg' },
    { title: '', image: 'images/pic6.jpg' },
    { title: '', image: 'images/pic7.jpg' },
    { title: '', image: 'images/pic8.jpg' },
    { title: '', image: 'images/pic9.jpg' },
    { title: '', image: 'images/pic10.jpg' }
  ];

  $scope.cards = Array.prototype.slice.call(cardTypes, 0, 0);

  $scope.cardSwiped = function(index) {
    $scope.addCard();
  };

  $scope.cardDestroyed = function(index) {
    if (this.swipeCard.positive === true) {
      $scope.$root.accepted++;
    } else {
      $scope.$root.rejected++;
    }
    $scope.cards.splice(index, 1);
  };

  $scope.addCard = function() {
    var newCard = cardTypes[Math.floor(Math.random() * cardTypes.length)];
    newCard.id = Math.random();
    $scope.cards.push(angular.extend({}, newCard));
  }
})

.controller('CardCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSwipeCardDelegate, $rootScope) {
  $scope.accept = function () {
    var card = $ionicSwipeCardDelegate.getSwipebleCard($scope);
    $rootScope.accepted++;
    card.swipe(true);
  }
  $scope.reject = function() {
    var card = $ionicSwipeCardDelegate.getSwipebleCard($scope);
    $rootScope.rejected++;
    card.swipe();
  };
});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you create a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xknhu3mm/

Comment: Here is the link i am working on :-http://112.196.33.85/solitaire/demoui/john/10oct/swiper.html

Answer (score 0):

i think your should add an attribute to all your object like `swaped` so when your swipe your have just to do `card.swaped = true;` and in your ng-repeat filter `card.swaped == true`

```
<swipe-card ng-repeat="card in cards | filter:swaped:false" on-swipe="cardSwiped($index)">
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion @Mathieu, can you please post the piece of the code i need to modify, I am new to Angular JS, your help will be appreciated.

Comment: just do in cadrSwiped `$scope.cards[$index].swaped = true`